# output the whole string in c++ using getline

Tags: c++, string

I wrote this code. It works in the main function

```
cout << "Enter the patron's name: ";
getline(std::cin, patron.name);
cout << "Enter the book title: ";
getline(std::cin, book.title);
cout << book.title << " is now checked out to " << patron.name << endl;
```

However, when I put it under a do while loop with switch case, it does not work anymore.

```
do {
        cout << endl << "? "; cin >> choice;
        switch (toupper(choice)){
        case 'T':           
            cout << "Enter the patron's name: ";
            getline(std::cin, patron.name);
            cout << "Enter the book title: ";               
            getline(std::cin, book.title);
            cout <<  book.title << " is now checked out to " << patron.name << endl;
            break;
           }[enter image description here][1]
} while (choice != 'Q' && choice!= 'q');
```

The input was like:

Could anyone explain to me why this happened? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After this statement

```
cout << endl << "? "; cin >> choice;
```

insert

```
std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );
```

to remove the new line character (that corresponds to the pressed Enter key after the input) that is still in the input buffer, Otherwise a call of `getline` will read an empty string.

You should include the header `<limits>` to use the class `numeric_limits`

Answer (score 0):

This `\n` after T(your input) is being consumed by getline. That's why you are getting such behaviour. You need  to flush the newline out of the buffer.

You can do this by adding this statement as shown.

```
std::cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
cout << "Enter the patron's name: ";
```